# Null token URI for ERC721 metadata on OpenSea TestNets

Tags: etherscan, opensea

I am relatively new to deploying ERC721 tokens for NFT collections and I have a quick question about why my token metadata isn't properly refreshing and showing the images, description, name and traits.

I am getting the following response from the OpenSea testnet API:

[image: OpenSea Validate Asset]

It's showing that my token_uri is null, but I've followed the steps of Alchemy's docs and implemented my `ipfs://<cid>` into the `uri` section of my `safeMint` function in Etherscan:
[image: Screenshot of etherscan for safemint]

The CID points to a metadata folder with 100 JSON files in it that include the name, id, description, traits and the image link pointing to IPFS.

I have refreshed the metadata like 100 times and nothing has changed. I've gone through and forced the refresh via the testnet opensea api, and still nothing.

Here is the Testnet OpenSea collection -> https://testnets.opensea.io/collection/beaver-believers

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Are you following [this](https://docs.alchemy.com/docs/how-to-develop-an-nft-smart-contract-erc721-with-alchemy) tutorial?

It seems like you never provide the NFT metadata. It is included in the later section of this tutorial.

I love Beavers, Happy coding!